# Conflict in Free and dmidecode

Tags: linux

I notice that System RAM is Conflict at actual.

***Free***:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2948084    1710456    1237628      60700     637336     418016
-/+ buffers/cache:     655104    2292980 
Swap:      3080188          0    3080188
```

***`dmidecode`***:

```
Handle 0x0006, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: A0
    Bank Connections: 0 1
    Current Speed: Unknown
    Type: Other
    Installed Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: A1
    Bank Connections: 2 3
    Current Speed: Unknown
    Type: Other
    Installed Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001A
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A0
    Bank Locator: Bank0/1
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: None
    Serial Number: None
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: None

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x001A
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1
    Bank Locator: Bank2/3
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: None
    Serial Number: None
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: None

System is 64 Bit , centos 6.8.
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E4500 @ 2.20GHz
```

Here is Big Conflict that dmidecode show 2 GB RAM , Free show 3 GB RAM and System Bios show 3.3 GB RAM DDR2. I also changing RAM with with New one but getting same result.

Comment: try to run free with `-h` switch, and remember the K in computers world it 1024, not 1000

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

please see below result.(computers world it 1024)

### free -h total used free shared buffers cached Mem: 2.8G 2.7G 95M 171M 33M 336M -/+ buffers/cache: 2.4G 465M Swap: 2.9G 458M 2.5G